# Css shadow applying to svg box

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a shape that I exported from illustrator to SVG.  There is no background.  If this was a PNG I could set a shadow and it would start at the shape but when I set a shadow on the SVG it doesn't apply to the shape it applies to the invisible box.

Here is example to show what I mean:

```css
body{
  background-color: #000;
}

.oval{
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #fff;
}

img{
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img class="oval" src="http://gdurl.com/4EiW" alt="oval" />
```

How do I make the shadow apply to just the shape?

Comment: modify the image and set a drop shadow in the image file itself. You may need to set an SVG shadow via feGaussianBlur and feOffset elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to use svg shadows:

```html
<svg width="500" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="shadow">
      <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="8" stdDeviation="4"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <ellipse cx="200" cy="80" rx="100" ry="50"
      style="fill:blue; filter:url(#shadow);"/>
</svg>
```

**Update ! Animated Svg :**

```css
body {
  background: #E75B47;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-89deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.10) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-89deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.10) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-89deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.10) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-89deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.10) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
  text-align: center;
}

.bolt {
  fill: hsl(7, 50%, 38%);
  filter: url(#bolt-inner-shadow);
}

.bolt.loading {
  -webkit-animation: light-pulse 3s infinite;
  -moz-animation: light-pulse 3s infinite;
  animation: light-pulse 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes light-pulse {
  1%   { fill: hsl(7, 50%, 38%); }
  50%  { fill: hsl(7, 50%, 78%); }
  100% { fill: hsl(7, 50%, 38%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes light-pulse {
  1%   { fill: hsl(7, 50%, 38%); }
  50%  { fill: hsl(7, 50%, 78%); }
  100% { fill: hsl(7, 50%, 38%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  1%   { -webkit-transform: scale(0.7); }
  25%  { -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); }
  45%  { -webkit-transform: scale(0.9); }
  63%  { -webkit-transform: scale(1.05); }
  79%  { -webkit-transform: scale(0.95); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.0); }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  1%   { transform: scale(0.7); }
  25%  { transform: scale(1.1); }
  45%  { transform: scale(0.9); }
  63%  { transform: scale(1.05); }
  79%  { transform: scale(0.95); }
  100% { transform: scale(1.0); }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="258px" height="437px" viewBox="0 0 258 437" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="bolt-inner-shadow">
      <feOffset dx="0" dy="0" />
      <feGaussianBlur
        stdDeviation="8"
        result="offset-blur"
      />
      <feComposite
        operator='out'
        in='SourceGraphic'
        in2='offset-blur'
        result='inverse'
      />
      <feFlood
        flood-color='6B2C22'
        flood-opacity='1'
        result='color'
      />
    
      <!-- Clip color inside shadow -->
      <feComposite
        operator='in'
        in='color'
        in2='inverse'
        result='shadow'
      />
    
      <!-- Put shadow over original object -->
      <feComposite
        operator='over'
        in='shadow'
        in2='SourceGraphic'
      />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <path d="M12 240.2 L221.733736 6 L165.795158 192.5 L245.547254 191.8 L35.813518 426 L91.7520965 239.5 Z M12 240.2" class="bolt loading">
</svg>
```

Comment: I guess this is the only way.  I was hoping to animate it with CSS but this adds a lot of complexity for simple shadow animation as I don't know svg animation.  Unfortunately I think I will have to fallback to PNG in this case.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: you're welcome , if i find any way to animate it i will share ♥

Comment: @Guerrilla i have updated my answer take a look at it :)

Comment: Thanks, interesting example.  I wanted to animate the shadow as a glow effect so i don't think animating the fill will be able to produce the same result though.